# conemu: Change color scheme per shell?

Tags: conemu

conemu is pretty awesome, but is there a way to set a color profile for each individual shell? Like for powershell it uses one theme, for a cmd prompt it uses another, for putty another and so on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course yes, except of putty. Putty is NOT a shell, but only child GUI application you may run inside ConEmu tab or pane.

- using "-new_console:P:*PaletteName*" (look at "About/Help" dialog - Win+Alt+A)
- using "App distinct" settings, choose color palette there

Comment: @Maximus Hi! I use conEmu v. 14 a created a complete color scheme, but everytime a open a new tab or start application, it shows the the prefered scheme but immediately changes to something else. How can I resolve this annoying problem? Thanks

Comment: @XinHua You need to create an issue at the project tracker. With your configuration attached (ConEmu.xml) and description what are you running.